# When I want one object out of an firebaselistobservable using rxjs, should I still use subscribe?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs

I am kind of confused about which methods belong with and when to use them.

Right now, I am using subscribe for basically everything and it is not working for me when I want a quick static value out of Firebase. Can you explain when I should use subscribe vs other methods other than for a strict observable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with async values you have a few options: `promises`, `rxjs`, `callbacks`. Every option has its own drawbacks.

When you want to retrieve a single async value it is tempting to use promises for their simplicity (`.then(myVal => {})`). But this does not give you access to things like timeouts/throttling/retry behaviour etc. Rx streams, even for single values do give you these options.

So my recommendation would be, even if you want to have a single value, to use Observables. There is no async option for 'a quick static value out of a remote database'.

If you do not want to use the `.subscribe()` method there are other options which let you activate your subscription like `.toPromise()` which might be easier for retrieving a single value using Rx.

```
const getMyObjPromise = $firebase.get(myObjId)
  .timeout(5000)
  .retry(3)
  .toPromise()

getMyObjPromise.then(obj => console.log('got my object'));
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is, that you have a subscribe method that contains a bunch of logic like it was a ’.then’ and you save the result to some local variable.

First: try to avoid any logic inside the subscription-method -> use stream-operators before that and then subscribe just to retrieve the data.
You much more flexible with that and it is much easier to unit-test those single parts of your stream than to test a whole component in itself.

Second: try to avoid using a manual subscriptions at all - in angular controllers they are prone to cause memory leaks if not unsubscribed.
Use the async-pipe instead in your template and let angular manage the subscription itself.

Comment: Thank you this helped me understand a little more